# Make content fit in webbrowser in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser. I load a url with only a picture. The picture is larger than the webbrowser. How can I make the picture resize to fit the webbrowser so that the user won't need to zoom in and zoom out anymore?

Comment: Your url is a reference to html page or just a link to the .png/jpg? Why not to use native BitmapImage control to show the picture?

Comment: its a link to the .jpg. Some images cannot be displayed in BitmapImage. So I just want to play safe and use webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string html = String.Format("<html><head></head><body><img style='width:100%' src='{0}'/></body></html>",  "http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png");

webBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
```

You can add more styles for the image using 'style' attribute.

The following meta tag may be also interesting for you.

< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />